# Joining tables in different databases with the CI DataMapper ORM

Tags: php, mysql, join, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I did search for a solution, but found nothing helpfull. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448506/connecting-to-mulitple-databases-with-dmz-datamapper) question was about using multiple databases with datamapper but I already use that method.

user model:

```
class User extends DataMapper {
    var $prefix = "app_";

    var $db_params = 'default';
...
```

company model:

```
class Company extends DataMapper {
    var $prefix = "tbl_";

    var $db_params = 'super';
...
```

I have the above models. They are related as user-has-one-company and company-has-many-user.
When I create a company, a user will be created automatically and the relationship is made with succes.

However, when I try to delete a company, or try to acces the related company of a user. DataMapper looks for the user table in the wrong place.

I got the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1146

Table 'a1210alf.app_users' doesn't exist

SELECT `tbl_companies`.* FROM (`tbl_companies`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `app_users` app_users ON `tbl_companies`.`id` = `app_users`.`company_id` WHERE `app_users`.`id` = 4
```

In my CI config I have two different settings for two databases 'default' and 'super'. And I set the correct one in the model. The table app_users does exist, all fields needed are there. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this solution for a while now. It still didn't 'broke' in any case .. so I guess it's the correct way to do it.

First I created a 'BaseModel' which extends 'DataMapper'. The constructor looks like this:

```
/**
 * Constructor: calls parent constructor
 */
function __construct($id = NULL, $db = NULL)
{
    if ($db != NULL && $this->db_params == '') {    
        // use these params as default
        $this->db_params = array_merge(array( 
            'dbdriver'  => 'mysql',
            'pconnect'  => true,
            'db_debug'  => true,
            'cache_on'  => false,
            'char_set'  => 'utf8',
            'cachedir'  => '',
            'dbcollat'  => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'autoinit'  => true,
            'stricton'  => false,
        ), $db);
    }
    elseif($this->db_params == '') {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $cid = $CI->session->userdata('cid');
        if($cid != false || $cid != '') {
            $userDB = new Database();
            $userDB->get_where(array('company_id'=>$cid));
            if($userDB->exists()) {
                $this->db_params = array(
                    'hostname'      => $userDB->dbhost,
                    'database'      => $userDB->dbname,
                    'username'      => $userDB->dbuser,
                    'password'      => $userDB->dbpass,
                    'dbdriver'  => 'mysql',
                    'pconnect'  => true,
                    'db_debug'  => true,
                    'cache_on'  => false,
                    'char_set'  => 'utf8',
                    'cachedir'  => '',
                    'dbcollat'  => 'utf8_general_ci',
                    'autoinit'  => true,
                    'stricton'  => false,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    parent::__construct($id);
}
```

Now if you create an instance of a user we should do `$u = new User(NULL, $this->udb);` where `$this->udb` are the connection params which are loaded in the main controller.

This way the model will get the correct params each time. AND if a related object is needed the BaseModel knows where to get the correct params.

All I care about is that it works :p

NOTE: there is no need to set `var $db_params = 'default';` in each model. If you do, it will overwrite the params you set in the constructor of BaseModel.

Maybe this will be usefull to someone. But this was a special case and I don't encourage anyone to design their database this way if you are using CodeIgniter + Datamapper.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't resolve relations over different databases. You have to emulate this with your own logic.

Comment: Well it is possible, I'll edit the question with the code I use now.

Comment: No problem. Please note that the application used a different database for each 'company' that uses the application. That's why I can load the correct database connection parameters in a controller when someone logs in (which is ran on the default (shared) system database). If there aren't 'dynamic' params, the same approuch could be used by returning static params in your main controller.